# Why knex query fails without then clause?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

Why is the query not executed?

`knex.raw('truncate table sda_app.t_alerts')`

Only when I chain a `.then` will it run.

Comment: A lot of methods in knex are chainable to allow you to build your query. And by adding `then` method your are actually telling knex that you're done building and want the query to be executed.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.